# tabular with \setmainlanguage[numerals=maghrib]{arabic}

Tags: tables, xetex, polyglossia

i have this tabular

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,border=20pt,varwidth=1.3\linewidth]{standalone}
    \usepackage{mathtools}
    \usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
    \usepackage{polyglossia}
    %setting the arabic number 
    \setmainlanguage[numerals=maghrib]{arabic}
    %% Setting a font
    \newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic]{Amiri}
    \setotherlanguage{english}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \begin{document}
    \begin{enumerate}[itemsep=0pt,parsep=2pt]
    \item
    $0,45+0,25$
    \item
    \begin{tabular}{ c c c c c }
    0&,&2&5&\\
    0&,&4&5&+\\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \end{enumerate}
    \end{document}
```

But instead to get 0,25 i get 52,0 and instead to get 0,45+ i get +54,0.
My question how can i get the right 0,25 and 0,45+??

Answer (score 1):

To keep the table LTR you can change it into a math environment, such as `array`. These are normally centered, but you can wrap it in a `multline` environment which allows to use `\shoveleft`. The math environments create a gap above and below the table, which you can reduce by setting `\abovedisplayskip` and `\belowdisplayskip`.

Put together:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
%setting the arabic number 
\setmainlanguage[numerals=maghrib]{arabic}
%% Setting a font
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic]{Amiri}
\setotherlanguage{english}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[itemsep=0pt,parsep=2pt]
\item
$0,45+0,25$
\item \setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{-1Em}\setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{-1Em}
\begin{multline*}
\shoveleft{\begin{array}{ c c c c c }
0&,&2&5&\\
0&,&4&5&+\\
\hline
\end{array}}
\end{multline*}
\item $0,70$
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: very many thanks